# Spring: Enable EL in JSPs without web.xml

Tags: spring, jsp, el, web.xml, spring-java-config

I don't have a web.xml file, I use a class extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

EL is not enabled in JSPs.

Is there a way to enable EL without having to go back to using

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: EL should be enabled by default for the latest version of EL and the Servlet API. What versions are you on?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 8 so Servlet API 3.1 is included. Is there a dependency to add for EL?

Comment: Nope. It should be provided by tomcat.